# Delete expired documents in CouchDB

Tags: java, couchdb

I'm using couchDB to store some data and I'm having a problem with deleting the docs that was inserted before n days.

So, I treid to load the document I want do delete through a view and do a DELETE request for all of them at once; but failed.

**Sample Document :**

```
{
"date":"20160912",
"_id":"1xxxxx",
"name":"namal"
}
```

**View function :**

```
function (doc) {
       if(doc.date){
          emit(doc.date,doc);
       }
    }
```

**URL for loading documents :**

http://localhost:5984/dbx/_design/viewx/_view/date?key=%2220160910%22

**DELETE request :**

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:5984/dbx/_design/viewx/_view/date?key=%2220160910%22
```

I know that I can do this per document using _id and _rev like below.

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:5984/dbx/1xxxxx?rev="1-1111x1111111x222222x333333"
```

But in this case, I need to delete resulting document(s) one by one. What I want is, to delete a list of documents (bluk docs) at once (As I mentioned, the actual requremnet is to delete the docs that was inserted before n days).

Further, I know that the better way is to clear the expired data is by setting expiration time using CouchBase or MongoDb. But I'm looking for a solutin within the CouchDB implementation itself.

Note : In this case I want to make them really delete. Not invisible.

- Language : Java 1.7
- OS : Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit
- CouchDB version : 1.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CouchDB's bulk document API to update the documents (an update that sets the `_deleted` field to `true` is as good as a delete).

More info: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API#Modify_Multiple_Documents_With_a_Single_Request

For something more permanent, you can use CouchDB's `_purge` Command. [Details here](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Purge_Documents)

Note that this operation isn't replicated. So if you have a replication setup, you'll have to do this on each database.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it doesn't delete the document right? It make it  invisible. So, how can it be good as delete? And I want to make it actually delete as I mentioned in the problem.

Comment: This is 'delete' in CouchDB lingo. Are you looking for something that removes all trace and history of a document? And do you want such a 'permanent delete' to sync?

Comment: Thank you very much kul. I haven't try the purge command. I'll check on this.

Comment: I found a very important comment in the purge documentation that you referred. "If you are using _purge to recover space, you are almost certainly using CouchDB inappropriately. The most common reason developers use _purge inappropriately is when managing short-lived data (log entries, message queues, etc). A better remedy is to periodically switch to a new database and delete the old one (once the entries in it have all expired).". So, now I'm trying to create databases per day and delete the entire database when it is expired.